# Unable to generate cucumber report through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber-java

I am having error “Could not parse build number : ${${build.number}} while executing maven / java project through Jenkins.
If i run directly through Maven it works.
Any idea what could be the cause of this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the build number directly like,

`${BUILD_NUMBER}`  instead of `${${build.number}}`

otherwise you can pass it from goals and options sections.

```
clean install -Dbuild.number=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

then you can refer it in POM like `${build.number}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` instead of `${${build.number}}`